# Why won't this Android.mk build copy headers?

Tags: android-ndk

I have a simple Android.mk file for building libpng that I took from AOSP and modified slightly to build a shared lib instead of a static one.

```
  LOCAL_PATH:= $(call my-dir)
  LOCAL_CFLAGS := 
  LOCAL_COPY_HEADERS_TO := libs/include
  LOCAL_COPY_HEADERS := \
     png.h \
     pngconf.h \
     pngusr.h

  LOCAL_SRC_FILES := \
     png.c \
     pngerror.c \
     pnggccrd.c \
     pngget.c \
     pngmem.c \
     pngpread.c \
     pngread.c \
     pngrio.c \
     pngrtran.c \
     pngrutil.c \
     pngset.c \
     pngtrans.c \
     pngvcrd.c \
     pngwio.c \
     pngwrite.c \
     pngwtran.c \
     pngwutil.c

  LOCAL_LDLIBS := -lz

  LOCAL_MODULE := png
  LOCAL_MODULE_FILENAME := libpng

  include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

The LOCAL_COPY_HEADERS_TO and LOCAL_COPY_HEADERS options seem like they should copy the specified headers to the libs/include directory... but they don't do anything. The library itself seems to build correctly. I'm using verbose output for ndk-build and there are no errors. Here's the command I use (I just added escapes so the command would be easier to read):

```
ndk-build \
NDK_PROJECT_PATH=. \
APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=Android.mk \
TARGET_ARCH_ABI=armeabi-v7a \
TARGET_PLATFORM=android-9 \
V=1 NDK_LOG=1 -B
```

And here's the build output. Note that at the end install is only called on the lib binaries.

```
  HOST_OS=linux
  HOST_ARCH=x86_64
  HOST_TAG=linux-x86_64 
  GNUMAKE=/home/preet/Dev/env/sys/android-ndk-r8e/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/make (NDK prebuilt)
  Android NDK: NDK installation path auto-detected: '/home/preet/Dev/env/sys/android-ndk-r8e'
  Android NDK: GNU Make version 3.81 detected
  Android NDK: Host OS was auto-detected: linux
  Android NDK:  Host operating system detected: linux
  Android NDK: Host CPU was auto-detected: x86
  Android NDK: HOST_TAG set to linux-x86
  Android NDK: Host tools prebuilt directory: /home/preet/Dev/env/sys/android-ndk-r8e/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin
  Android NDK: Host 'echo' tool: echo
  Android NDK: Host 'echo -n' tool: printf %s
  Android NDK: Host 'cmp' tool: cmp
  Android NDK: Host 'awk' tool: /home/preet/Dev/env/sys/android-ndk-r8e/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/awk
  Android NDK: Host 'awk' test returned: Pass
  Android NDK: Found platform root directory: /home/preet/Dev/env/sys/android-ndk-r8e/platforms
  Android NDK: Found supported platforms: android-14 android-3 android-4 android-5 android-8 android-9
  Android NDK: PLATFORM android-14 supports: arm mips x86
  Android NDK:   ABI arm sysroot is: /home/preet/Dev/env/sys/android-ndk-r8e/platforms/android-14/arch-arm
  Android NDK:   ABI mips sysroot is: /home/preet/Dev/env/sys/android-ndk-r8e/platforms/android-14/arch-mips
  Android NDK:   ABI x86 sysroot is: /home/preet/Dev/env/sys/android-ndk-r8e/platforms/android-14/arch-x86
  Android NDK: PLATFORM android-3 supports: arm
  Android NDK:   ABI arm sysroot is: /home/preet/Dev/env/sys/android-ndk-r8e/platforms/android-3/arch-arm
  Android NDK: PLATFORM android-4 supports: arm
  Android NDK:   ABI arm sysroot is: /home/preet/Dev/env/sys/android-ndk-r8e/platforms/android-4/arch-arm
  Android NDK: PLATFORM android-5 supports: arm
  Android NDK:   ABI arm sysroot is: /home/preet/Dev/env/sys/android-ndk-r8e/platforms/android-5/arch-arm
  Android NDK: PLATFORM android-8 supports: arm
  Android NDK:   ABI arm sysroot is: /home/preet/Dev/env/sys/android-ndk-r8e/platforms/android-8/arch-arm
  Android NDK: PLATFORM android-9 supports: arm mips x86
  Android NDK:   ABI arm sysroot is: /home/preet/Dev/env/sys/android-ndk-r8e/platforms/android-9/arch-arm
  Android NDK:   ABI mips sysroot is: /home/preet/Dev/env/sys/android-ndk-r8e/platforms/android-9/arch-mips
  Android NDK:   ABI x86 sysroot is: /home/preet/Dev/env/sys/android-ndk-r8e/platforms/android-9/arch-x86
  Android NDK: Found stable platform levels: 14 3 4 5 8 9
  Android NDK: Found max platform level: 14
  Android NDK:  This NDK supports the following target architectures and ABIS:
  Android NDK:    arm: armeabi armeabi-v7a
  Android NDK:    mips: mips
  Android NDK:    x86: x86
  Android NDK:  This NDK supports the following toolchains and target ABIs:
  Android NDK:    arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3:  armeabi armeabi-v7a
  Android NDK:    arm-linux-androideabi-4.6:  armeabi armeabi-v7a
  Android NDK:    arm-linux-androideabi-4.7:  armeabi armeabi-v7a
  Android NDK:    arm-linux-androideabi-clang3.1:  armeabi armeabi-v7a
  Android NDK:    arm-linux-androideabi-clang3.2:  armeabi armeabi-v7a
  Android NDK:    mipsel-linux-android-4.4.3:  mips
  Android NDK:    mipsel-linux-android-4.6:  mips
  Android NDK:    mipsel-linux-android-4.7:  mips
  Android NDK:    mipsel-linux-android-clang3.1:  mips
  Android NDK:    mipsel-linux-android-clang3.2:  mips
  Android NDK:    x86-4.4.3:  x86
  Android NDK:    x86-4.6:  x86
  Android NDK:    x86-4.7:  x86
  Android NDK:    x86-clang3.1:  x86
  Android NDK:    x86-clang3.2:  x86
  Android NDK: Found project path: .
  Android NDK: Ouput path: ./obj
  Android NDK: Parsing /home/preet/Dev/env/sys/android-ndk-r8e/build/core/default-application.mk
  Android NDK:   Defaulted to APP_PLATFORM=android-3
  Android NDK:   APP_PIE is 
  Android NDK:   Using build script Android.mk
  Android NDK: Application 'local' is not debuggable
  Android NDK: Selecting release optimization mode (app is not debuggable)
  Android NDK: Adding import directory: /home/preet/Dev/env/sys/android-ndk-r8e/sources
  Android NDK: Building application 'local' for ABI 'armeabi-v7a'
  Android NDK: Using target toolchain 'arm-linux-androideabi-4.6' for 'armeabi-v7a' ABI
  Android NDK: Looking for imported module with tag 'cxx-stl/system'
  Android NDK:   Probing /home/preet/Dev/env/sys/android-ndk-r8e/sources/cxx-stl/system/Android.mk
  Android NDK:     Found in /home/preet/Dev/env/sys/android-ndk-r8e/sources/cxx-stl/system
  rm -f ./libs/armeabi/lib*.so ./libs/armeabi-v7a/lib*.so ./libs/mips/lib*.so ./libs/x86/lib*.so
  rm -f ./libs/armeabi/gdbserver ./libs/armeabi-v7a/gdbserver ./libs/mips/gdbserver ./libs/x86/gdbserver
  rm -f ./libs/armeabi/gdb.setup ./libs/armeabi-v7a/gdb.setup ./libs/mips/gdb.setup ./libs/x86/gdb.setup
  Compile thumb  : png <= png.c
  /home/preet/Dev/env/sys/android-ndk-r8e/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc -MMD -MP -MF ./obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/png/png.o.d -fpic -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector -no-canonical-prefixes -march=armv7-a -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=vfpv3-d16 -mthumb -Os -g -DNDEBUG -fomit-frame-pointer -fno-strict-aliasing -finline-limit=64 -I. -DANDROID  -Wa,--noexecstack  -I/home/preet/Dev/env/sys/android-ndk-r8e/platforms/android-9/arch-arm/usr/include -c  ./png.c -o ./obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/png/png.o 
  Compile thumb  : png <= pngerror.c
  /home/preet/Dev/env/sys/android-ndk-r8e/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc -MMD -MP -MF ./obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/png/pngerror.o.d -fpic -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector -no-canonical-prefixes -march=armv7-a -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=vfpv3-d16 -mthumb -Os -g -DNDEBUG -fomit-frame-pointer -fno-strict-aliasing -finline-limit=64 -I. -DANDROID  -Wa,--noexecstack  -I/home/preet/Dev/env/sys/android-ndk-r8e/platforms/android-9/arch-arm/usr/include -c  ./pngerror.c -o ./obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/png/pngerror.o 
  Compile thumb  : png <= pnggccrd.c
  /home/preet/Dev/env/sys/android-ndk-r8e/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc -MMD -MP -MF ./obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/png/pnggccrd.o.d -fpic -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector -no-canonical-prefixes -march=armv7-a -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=vfpv3-d16 -mthumb -Os -g -DNDEBUG -fomit-frame-pointer -fno-strict-aliasing -finline-limit=64 -I. -DANDROID  -Wa,--noexecstack  -I/home/preet/Dev/env/sys/android-ndk-r8e/platforms/android-9/arch-arm/usr/include -c  ./pnggccrd.c -o ./obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/png/pnggccrd.o 
  Compile thumb  : png <= pngget.c
  /home/preet/Dev/env/sys/android-ndk-r8e/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc -MMD -MP -MF ./obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/png/pngget.o.d -fpic -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector -no-canonical-prefixes -march=armv7-a -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=vfpv3-d16 -mthumb -Os -g -DNDEBUG -fomit-frame-pointer -fno-strict-aliasing -finline-limit=64 -I. -DANDROID  -Wa,--noexecstack  -I/home/preet/Dev/env/sys/android-ndk-r8e/platforms/android-9/arch-arm/usr/include -c  ./pngget.c -o ./obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/png/pngget.o 
  Compile thumb  : png <= pngmem.c
  /home/preet/Dev/env/sys/android-ndk-r8e/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc -MMD -MP -MF ./obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/png/pngmem.o.d -fpic -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector -no-canonical-prefixes -march=armv7-a -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=vfpv3-d16 -mthumb -Os -g -DNDEBUG -fomit-frame-pointer -fno-strict-aliasing -finline-limit=64 -I. -DANDROID  -Wa,--noexecstack  -I/home/preet/Dev/env/sys/android-ndk-r8e/platforms/android-9/arch-arm/usr/include -c  ./pngmem.c -o ./obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/png/pngmem.o 
  Compile thumb  : png <= pngpread.c
  /home/preet/Dev/env/sys/android-ndk-r8e/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc -MMD -MP -MF ./obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/png/pngpread.o.d -fpic -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector -no-canonical-prefixes -march=armv7-a -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=vfpv3-d16 -mthumb -Os -g -DNDEBUG -fomit-frame-pointer -fno-strict-aliasing -finline-limit=64 -I. -DANDROID  -Wa,--noexecstack  -I/home/preet/Dev/env/sys/android-ndk-r8e/platforms/android-9/arch-arm/usr/include -c  ./pngpread.c -o ./obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/png/pngpread.o 
  Compile thumb  : png <= pngread.c
  /home/preet/Dev/env/sys/android-ndk-r8e/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc -MMD -MP -MF ./obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/png/pngread.o.d -fpic -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector -no-canonical-prefixes -march=armv7-a -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=vfpv3-d16 -mthumb -Os -g -DNDEBUG -fomit-frame-pointer -fno-strict-aliasing -finline-limit=64 -I. -DANDROID  -Wa,--noexecstack  -I/home/preet/Dev/env/sys/android-ndk-r8e/platforms/android-9/arch-arm/usr/include -c  ./pngread.c -o ./obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/png/pngread.o 
  Compile thumb  : png <= pngrio.c
  /home/preet/Dev/env/sys/android-ndk-r8e/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc -MMD -MP -MF ./obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/png/pngrio.o.d -fpic -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector -no-canonical-prefixes -march=armv7-a -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=vfpv3-d16 -mthumb -Os -g -DNDEBUG -fomit-frame-pointer -fno-strict-aliasing -finline-limit=64 -I. -DANDROID  -Wa,--noexecstack  -I/home/preet/Dev/env/sys/android-ndk-r8e/platforms/android-9/arch-arm/usr/include -c  ./pngrio.c -o ./obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/png/pngrio.o 
  Compile thumb  : png <= pngrtran.c
  /home/preet/Dev/env/sys/android-ndk-r8e/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc -MMD -MP -MF ./obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/png/pngrtran.o.d -fpic -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector -no-canonical-prefixes -march=armv7-a -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=vfpv3-d16 -mthumb -Os -g -DNDEBUG -fomit-frame-pointer -fno-strict-aliasing -finline-limit=64 -I. -DANDROID  -Wa,--noexecstack  -I/home/preet/Dev/env/sys/android-ndk-r8e/platforms/android-9/arch-arm/usr/include -c  ./pngrtran.c -o ./obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/png/pngrtran.o 
  Compile thumb  : png <= pngrutil.c
  /home/preet/Dev/env/sys/android-ndk-r8e/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc -MMD -MP -MF ./obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/png/pngrutil.o.d -fpic -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector -no-canonical-prefixes -march=armv7-a -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=vfpv3-d16 -mthumb -Os -g -DNDEBUG -fomit-frame-pointer -fno-strict-aliasing -finline-limit=64 -I. -DANDROID  -Wa,--noexecstack  -I/home/preet/Dev/env/sys/android-ndk-r8e/platforms/android-9/arch-arm/usr/include -c  ./pngrutil.c -o ./obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/png/pngrutil.o 
  Compile thumb  : png <= pngset.c
  /home/preet/Dev/env/sys/android-ndk-r8e/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc -MMD -MP -MF ./obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/png/pngset.o.d -fpic -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector -no-canonical-prefixes -march=armv7-a -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=vfpv3-d16 -mthumb -Os -g -DNDEBUG -fomit-frame-pointer -fno-strict-aliasing -finline-limit=64 -I. -DANDROID  -Wa,--noexecstack  -I/home/preet/Dev/env/sys/android-ndk-r8e/platforms/android-9/arch-arm/usr/include -c  ./pngset.c -o ./obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/png/pngset.o 
  Compile thumb  : png <= pngtrans.c
  /home/preet/Dev/env/sys/android-ndk-r8e/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc -MMD -MP -MF ./obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/png/pngtrans.o.d -fpic -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector -no-canonical-prefixes -march=armv7-a -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=vfpv3-d16 -mthumb -Os -g -DNDEBUG -fomit-frame-pointer -fno-strict-aliasing -finline-limit=64 -I. -DANDROID  -Wa,--noexecstack  -I/home/preet/Dev/env/sys/android-ndk-r8e/platforms/android-9/arch-arm/usr/include -c  ./pngtrans.c -o ./obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/png/pngtrans.o 
  Compile thumb  : png <= pngvcrd.c
  /home/preet/Dev/env/sys/android-ndk-r8e/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc -MMD -MP -MF ./obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/png/pngvcrd.o.d -fpic -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector -no-canonical-prefixes -march=armv7-a -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=vfpv3-d16 -mthumb -Os -g -DNDEBUG -fomit-frame-pointer -fno-strict-aliasing -finline-limit=64 -I. -DANDROID  -Wa,--noexecstack  -I/home/preet/Dev/env/sys/android-ndk-r8e/platforms/android-9/arch-arm/usr/include -c  ./pngvcrd.c -o ./obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/png/pngvcrd.o 
  Compile thumb  : png <= pngwio.c
  /home/preet/Dev/env/sys/android-ndk-r8e/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc -MMD -MP -MF ./obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/png/pngwio.o.d -fpic -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector -no-canonical-prefixes -march=armv7-a -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=vfpv3-d16 -mthumb -Os -g -DNDEBUG -fomit-frame-pointer -fno-strict-aliasing -finline-limit=64 -I. -DANDROID  -Wa,--noexecstack  -I/home/preet/Dev/env/sys/android-ndk-r8e/platforms/android-9/arch-arm/usr/include -c  ./pngwio.c -o ./obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/png/pngwio.o 
  Compile thumb  : png <= pngwrite.c
  /home/preet/Dev/env/sys/android-ndk-r8e/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc -MMD -MP -MF ./obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/png/pngwrite.o.d -fpic -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector -no-canonical-prefixes -march=armv7-a -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=vfpv3-d16 -mthumb -Os -g -DNDEBUG -fomit-frame-pointer -fno-strict-aliasing -finline-limit=64 -I. -DANDROID  -Wa,--noexecstack  -I/home/preet/Dev/env/sys/android-ndk-r8e/platforms/android-9/arch-arm/usr/include -c  ./pngwrite.c -o ./obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/png/pngwrite.o 
  Compile thumb  : png <= pngwtran.c
  /home/preet/Dev/env/sys/android-ndk-r8e/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc -MMD -MP -MF ./obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/png/pngwtran.o.d -fpic -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector -no-canonical-prefixes -march=armv7-a -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=vfpv3-d16 -mthumb -Os -g -DNDEBUG -fomit-frame-pointer -fno-strict-aliasing -finline-limit=64 -I. -DANDROID  -Wa,--noexecstack  -I/home/preet/Dev/env/sys/android-ndk-r8e/platforms/android-9/arch-arm/usr/include -c  ./pngwtran.c -o ./obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/png/pngwtran.o 
  Compile thumb  : png <= pngwutil.c
  /home/preet/Dev/env/sys/android-ndk-r8e/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc -MMD -MP -MF ./obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/png/pngwutil.o.d -fpic -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector -no-canonical-prefixes -march=armv7-a -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=vfpv3-d16 -mthumb -Os -g -DNDEBUG -fomit-frame-pointer -fno-strict-aliasing -finline-limit=64 -I. -DANDROID  -Wa,--noexecstack  -I/home/preet/Dev/env/sys/android-ndk-r8e/platforms/android-9/arch-arm/usr/include -c  ./pngwutil.c -o ./obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/png/pngwutil.o 
  SharedLibrary  : libpng.so
  /home/preet/Dev/env/sys/android-ndk-r8e/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-g++ -Wl,-soname,libpng.so -shared --sysroot=/home/preet/Dev/env/sys/android-ndk-r8e/platforms/android-9/arch-arm ./obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/png/png.o ./obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/png/pngerror.o ./obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/png/pnggccrd.o ./obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/png/pngget.o ./obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/png/pngmem.o ./obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/png/pngpread.o ./obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/png/pngread.o ./obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/png/pngrio.o ./obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/png/pngrtran.o ./obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/png/pngrutil.o ./obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/png/pngset.o ./obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/png/pngtrans.o ./obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/png/pngvcrd.o ./obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/png/pngwio.o ./obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/png/pngwrite.o ./obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/png/pngwtran.o ./obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/png/pngwutil.o -lgcc -no-canonical-prefixes -march=armv7-a -Wl,--fix-cortex-a8  -Wl,--no-undefined -Wl,-z,noexecstack -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now  -L/home/preet/Dev/env/sys/android-ndk-r8e/platforms/android-9/arch-arm/usr/lib -lz -lc -lm -o ./obj/local/armeabi-v7a/libpng.so
  Install        : libpng.so => libs/armeabi-v7a/libpng.so
  install -p ./obj/local/armeabi-v7a/libpng.so ./libs/armeabi-v7a/libpng.so
  /home/preet/Dev/env/sys/android-ndk-r8e/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-strip --strip-unneeded  ./libs/armeabi-v7a/libpng.so
```

Answer (score 0):

You messed up your order.  You should have:

```
LOCAL_COPY_HEADERS := \
     png.h \
     pngconf.h \
     pngusr.h
```

followed by:

```
LOCAL_COPY_HEADERS_TO := libs/include
```

(You must dictate your headers, then tell the system where to copy them to.) It could also have been deprecated on your current sdk too.